# How to avoid the checkbox from being overlapped by the text in UITableView

Tags: ios5, uitableview

I am able to add a checkbox to the UITableView but the checkbox is partially hidden by the text in the UITableView. Can anyone tell me how to align the two in the cell as the checkbox is hidden by the text.
This is the code for adding the checkbox.

```
UIButton *checkBox=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    checkBox.tag=indexPath.row;
    checkBox.frame=CGRectMake(2,12, 15, 15);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:checkBox];
    [checkBox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [checkBox addTarget:self action:@selector(checkBoxClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the cell's built-in label (or labels, depending on type), create your own label and add it as subview of the cell. This way, the custom label won't be autoresized or otherwise manipulated by the cell, potentially undoing your settings.

Comment: Could you help me with how to save the state of the checkbox? The checkbox remains unselected on scrolling the uitableview

Comment: I think the 'checked' state should be saved with your data model (whatever array you are using to configure table cells on dequeue/reuse).  What does each cell represent? What is the meaning of the box being checked?

Comment: Perhaps you should post a new question and explain there what kind of data your table displays and how

Comment: If each row (cell) represents an object of a custom class, you probably want to add a BOOL property that represents the checkbox state.

Comment: But how do u get the selected row?

Comment: This is beyond the scope; there is a 'canonical' way of populating table views, it's all over the internet... Like I said, post a new question!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the cell.textLabel.frame to move it right by 15 points (and reduce it's width by 15 points too). Something like this:

```
cell.textLabel.frame.origin.x += 15;
cell.textLabel.frame.size.width -= 15;
```

Comment: No changes are seen. I tried different values and parameters.

Comment: Perhaps that's because it's the built-in label. Try adding a custom label as a subview of the cell and resize that one. Leave the default one empty, unused.

Comment: My guess is that UITableViewCell does some autoresizing etc. behind the scenes on its built-in subviews, and many changes you apply get 'undone'.